# flash messages in a modal in Grails

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap-3, spring-security

I'm using [security core Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) in my application , but i changed the login page to be a modal , below is the code , the problem that the flash message doesn't show in the modal although i added the part to show the flash messages .

Modal :

```
<!-- *** LOGIN MODAL ***_________________________________________________________
-->
<div id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true"
    class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</button>
                <h4 id="Login" class="modal-title">Customer login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <g:if test='${flash.message}'>
                    <div class="message" role="status">
                        ${flash.message}
                    </div>
                </g:if>
                <form action='./j_spring_security_check' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform'
                    autocomplete='off'>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type='text' class='form-control' name='j_username' id='username'
                            placeholder="${message(code:'springSecurity.login.username.label') }" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type='password' class='form-control' name='j_password' id='password'
                            placeholder="${message(code:'springSecurity.login.password.label') }" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                            ${message(code: 'springSecurity.login.button')}
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </form>
                <p class="text-center text-muted">
                    <g:link controller="users" action="create">
                        <g:message code="spring.security.ui.login.register" default="New User" />
                    </g:link>
                </p>
                <p class="text-center text-muted">
                    <g:link controller="register" action="forgotPassword">
                        <g:message code="spring.security.ui.login.forgotPassword" default="Forgot Password" />
                    </g:link>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- *** LOGIN MODAL END ***-->
```

Comment: When are you fetching the modal template - separately or together with the main view?

Comment: @GregorPetrin together with the main view <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"> ${message(code:'spring.security.ui.login.login') } <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>